# Error when trying to deploy an adapter to MobileFirst Platform 6.3 running on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to deploy a MobileFirst adapter to MobileFirst Server 6.3 running on Tomcat 7.

Snippet from the Ant script:

```
<wladm url="${resolved.worklight.server.url}/${worklight.admin.context}" secure="false" user="${worklight.server.user}" password="${worklight.server.password}">
          <deploy-adapter runtime="ProjectName" file="${basedir}/bin/MyAdapter.adapter"/>
</wladm>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
-deploy-adapter:
[wladm] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[wladm] <config userName="demouser" productVersion="6.3.0.00-20141127-1357"/>
[wladm] Error accessing http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/ProjectName/adapters?locale=en_US: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080 failed to respond
```

Weird is that when I run the same Ant script but pointing to my local workspace running WAS Liberty in the development studio (Eclipse), it works fine.

Also, the deployment of an application to application console and native app to appcenter works fine with Tomcat, the issue is only when deploying an adapter.

Any idea?

Comment: Try changing the values to their actual values instead of variable; perhaps one of them is incorrect?

Comment: They are ok and are the same that i use to deploy application and query serverinfo 


  <wladm url="${resolved.worklight.server.url}/${worklight.admin.context}" secure="false" user="${worklight.server.user}" password="${worklight.server.password}">
       <show-info/>
     </wladm>
  
  
  <wladm url="${resolved.worklight.server.url}/${worklight.admin.context}" secure="false" user="${worklight.server.user}" password="${worklight.server.password}">
        <deploy-app runtime="ProjectName" file="${basedir}/bin/${app.name}-all.wlapp"/>
     </wladm>

Comment: I could get it to fail on "connection refused", but not "failed to respond"...

Comment: At least in my case it happens when you can not reach the context,  i.g pointing to a wrong context.
What i can add is that sometimes, when i got the "failed to respond" i saw a 401 in tomcat access log for the path "management-apis/1.0/runtimes/ProjectName/adapters?locale=en_US:"

Comment: I see you are from IBM. you have an email from Bruno H from IBM about this very issue and he sent to you a question which still awaits a reply from you - please reply to him and add me as CC (Idan Adar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find a fix for this issue

Well, i did try deploy the adapter using cURL and it works.

So after it i did try deploy the adapter, passing this parameter to the JVM that ant is using

```
-Dcom.ibm.worklight.allow-100-continue=false
```

and the adapter was deployed.